# R DOLS (Dynamic Ordinary Least Squares) packages

Tags: r, regression

I've been messing around with different regression options in **R** and noticed that I haven't see any regression options that explicitly state they're implementing a **DOLS** algorithm. Many of the statistical papers mention the algorithm but when I go through source code for packages like **urca** or **tseries** I see them just using the standard **lm** package. For instance, **urca**'s `ca.po` test and **tseries**' `po.test` both use straight **lm** to estimate the residual for the test. Is it possible to simulate **DOLS** using **lm** or **dynlm**?

I'm asking because I'd like to use **DOLS** for some stuff I've been working on and I can't figure out how to either simulate it with an existing package or what I'd need to write.

Comment: For future reference there is now a package on CRAN implementing the panel dynamic ols estimator of cointegrating vectors by Mark and Sul (2003). https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdolsms/pdolsms.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong about this, because I know nothing of your area, but I believe the `vars` package has everything you are looking for. It has a [fabulous vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf), I think you are looking for the `stability` function, particularly the `dynamic` argument. Note that this function just wraps another from the package `strucchange`.

Then again, I might be way off the mark if you *aren't* in econometrics.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look and see if it does what I'm after.